# How does buffer works in node js?

Tags: node.js

I'm new in node js and trying to broadcast video streaming, but not getting any idea how to do this. Want to know how buffering works in a node js application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a buffer in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551006/what-is-a-buffer-in-node-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Buffers are instances of the Buffer class in node, which is designed to handle raw binary data. Each buffer corresponds to some raw memory allocated outside V8. Buffers act somewhat like arrays of integers, but aren't resizable and have a whole bunch of methods specifically for binary data. In addition, the "integers" in a buffer each represent a byte and so are limited to values from 0 to 255 (2^8 - 1), inclusive.

More about buffers [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/docs/blob/master/pages/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers/content.md).

Looks something like this:
[image: 1]

Data is processed in terms of streams , instead whole of data at a time. These streams are collected in a buffer and once the buffer is full, the streams are passed on from one point to another (to the client requesting the data).

[image: 2]

something like streaming movies online. This way we don't have to wait for the whole of data to arrive but receive in chunk and start using it even before the data is arrived. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlybFFMXXmQ) is simple and helpful.